# Matplotlib Colorbar assigining different bins to custom colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to create a custom colorbar using matplotlib with different bin intervals with the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([(1, 1,1, 0),
                                        (237/255, 239/255, 243/255, 1.0),              #whitesmoke
                                        (172/255, 180/255,206/255, 1.0),              #mediumslateblue
                                        (161/255,215/255,227/255, 1.0),          #lightskyblue
                                        (143/255,200/255,145/255, 1.0),          #seagreen
                                        (249/255,236/255,51/255, 1.0),          #yellow
                                        (238/255,181/255,9/255, 1.0),          #gold
                                        (233/255,135/255,45/255, 1.0),          #orange
                                        (223/255,83/255,42/255, 1.0),          #darkorange
                                        (217/255,38/255,42/255, 1.0)])          #red

            
bounds= [0.02,0.07,0.28,1.14,4.63,8.60,15.70,28.66,52.39,95.69]
ticks=[0.02,0.07,0.28,1.14,4.63,8.60,15.70,28.66,52.39,95.69]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
cb2 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap,
                                        norm=norm,
                                        boundaries=ticks,
                                         ticks=bounds,
                                        spacing='proportional',
                                        orientation='horizontal')
```

[Colorbar output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoKlT.png)

My problem is that I want the colorbar to come out as equal bins of colors but assign values in the dataset according to that bin. but as you can see the bins on the colorbar is not even and small bins can not be read? Can you please help me point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks you in advanced.

Comment: So, in reality you want the default `spacing='uniform'` instead of `spacing='proportional'`?  Note that you need 11 bounds when you have 10 colors (your example only shows 9 colors, 'gold' isn't used as 10 bounds only delimit 9 regions).

Comment: @JohanC Thank you very much that helped me to get where I was trying for. I didint know that argument was possible.